# Error with WaterMarkTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get this project to work but I keep getting two errors:

- Error 1  The type 'xctk:WatermarkTextBox' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
- Error 2  The attachable property 'Text' was not found in type 'WatermarkTextBox'.

I tried including namespace in two ways:

```
xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
```

and like this:

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

Here is look at part of code that gives me errors when I use it:

```
<xctk:WatermarkTextBox Name="txtSign" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,3,27,20"  Watermark="Put your sign here" >
                <xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Type.Sign" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <validation:ValidacionType1 ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                            <validation:ValidacionType1 ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Text>

                <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"  Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="White" Background="Black" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            </xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
```

Everything worked until I added this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you [add the Xceed toolkit to the project with nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Extended WPF Toolkit assemblies from somewhere and reference them from your application. These assemblies are not part of the .NET Framework.

The easiest way to do this is to use the NuGet package manager console from within Visual Studio.

Select Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and type in the [Install-Package command](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/) suggested by @Ed Plunkett. This command will download and reference the appropriate assemblies (.dll files) for you.

You should then be able to build your application and use the `WatermarkTextBox` control.